# Как передать 0 в insert PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть такой код:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into body_price (price_group, price_item) VALUES ( :param_group , :param_item) ");
                        $stmt->bindValue("param_group" , 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $stmt->bindValue("param_item", 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $stmt->execute();
```

из консоли с таким запросом всё создаётся, из PHP — нет. Если изменить параметры на 1, всё создаётся. Как это победить?

В общем сам и отвечу.
PDO В циклах ведёт себя довольно странно по сравнению с mysqli. В цикле эта конструкция просто не работает не выдавая ничего.
Чтобы работало, подготавливаем запрос до цикла и в цикле только bind или execute с массивом. После этих манипуляций всё заработало.

Comment: у вас в три столбца вставляется 3 значения. оно так не работает

Comment: *два значения, опечатался

Comment: я к сожалению тоже печатался,  код выглядит так как сейчас.

Comment: А ошибки какие? $pdo->errorinfo()

Comment: В том то и дело что никаких, эта конструкция была в цикле, prepare нельзя делать в цикле, там по всей видимости какие то ограничения, когда я вынес prepare за пределы цикла всё заработало корректно. Я только начал изучать PDO. От mysqli оно отличается сильно, буду грызть дальше.